# Splitting in string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to split a string in JavaScript with the "`,`" as seperator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var splitString = yourstring.split(',');
```

See **[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split)**

```
var str = "test,test1,test2";
var arrStr = str.split(',');
var arrLength = arrStr.length; //returns 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split) to split your string:

```
"foo,bar,baz".split(",")  // returns ["foo","bar","baz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

var expression = "h,e,l,l,o";

var tokens = expression.split("\,");

alert(tokens[0]);// will return h

Comment: why are you splitting on `\,`? Is that just a typo?