# How do I spit a string and test for the start of a string in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Splitting in string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198713/splitting-in-string-in-javascript)
>   [javascript startswith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith)

Hello 
I have a string in javascript and I need to manipulate it. The string format is as follow

```
xxx_yyy
```

I need to:

- reproduce the behaviour of the `string.StartsWith("xxx_")` in c#
- split the string in two strings as I would do with `string.Split("_")` in c#

any help ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of two other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198713/splitting-in-string-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no jQuery needed here, just plain JavaScript has all you need with [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), for example:

```
var str = "xxx_yyy";
var startsWith = str.indexOf("xxx_") === 0;
var stringArray = str.split("_");
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TXC5q/).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(pattern) {
   return this.indexOf(pattern) === 0;
};
```

[`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) is already defined as a `String` method, and you can now use your newly created `startsWith` method like this:

```
var startsWithXXX = string.startsWith('xxx_'); //true
var array = string.split('_'); //['xxx', 'yyy'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily emulate StartsWith() by using JavaScript's `string.indexOf()`:

```
var startsWith = function(string, pattern){
    return string.indexOf(pattern) == 0;
}
```

And you can simply use JavaScript's [`string.split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method to split.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has split built-in.

```
'xxx_yyy'.split('_'); //produces ['xxx','yyy']

String.prototype.startsWith = function( str ) {
  return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
}


'xxx_yyy'.startsWith('xxx'); //produces true
```

Comment: This wouldn't test correctly, since you're testing with a string, not a regex.

Comment: of course after I post this, there are 3 more answers. I should try to avoid easy questions. :(